# Google indexing page with parameters but page is Disallowed in robots.txt

Tags: seo, google, robots.txt

I have the following in robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /refer.php

User-agent: NinjaBot
Allow: /

Sitemap: http://www.mysite.com/sitemap.xml
```

The `refer.php` file does various things depending on what `GET` parameters are passed to it.

When I do a Google search, I see tons of results for pages like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/refer.php?o=23945
http://www.mysite.com/refer.php?o=39858
http://www.mysite.com/refer.php?o=9683
http://www.mysite.com/refer.php?o=10569
http://www.mysite.com/refer.php?o=58304
http://www.mysite.com/refer.php?o=69604
```

Is the reason that Google is indexing these because I don't have an asterisk `*` after `refer.php` in the `robots.txt` ? Should changing it to `Disallow: /refer.php*` fix the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your robots.txt is just fine. However, it might not be enough to totally prevent indexing: Disallow command in robots.txt will block crawling, but in some cases the URLs themselves will still be indexed because of links or other factors.

Robots.txt is not meant to prevent the *indexing* of URLs, its purpose is to prevent *crawling*.

Best way to prevent Google from indexing an URL is to use this in the document head:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
```

[Google Help](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449):

> While Google won't crawl or index the content of pages blocked by
>   robots.txt, we may still index the URLs if we find them on other pages
>   on the web. As a result, the URL of the page and, potentially, other
>   publicly available information such as anchor text in links to the
>   site, or the title from the Open Directory Project (www.dmoz.org), can
>   appear in Google search results.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need an asterisk after, as leaving the path open without a dollar sign should match anything after. Maybe as its ending in php is causing an issue. In this case I might try:

```
Disallow: /*refer.php?
```

Also maybe obvious, but how long has the robots.txt been in place? I have seen Google take up too and over couple of weeks before updating the SERPS to reflect robots.txt changes.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
Disallow: /refer.php?*
```

To your robots.txt. Googlebot understand the wildcard and is the most explicit way to tell them not to index the URLs you want.

For working with all robots, try without the trailing * but do test using the Google Webmaster Tools robot tester to make sure Googlebot will be blocked.