# How much Google takes to deindex pages after disallowed from robots?

Tags: google-search-console, robots.txt, google-index, noindex

By accident I have let Google index lots of junk pages. Now I have added them to disallow in *robots.txt*.

Will Google completely remove the pages after seeing the are disallowed from robots? Please note that I have far to many pages to manually remove these pages in Google's Webmaster Tools.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the volume of URLS that need removing it could take weeks to months, Google simply doesn't like to quickly drop pages as it gives some time in case the webmaster has made a mistake. So you either need to be patient or simply remove them using the tool.

Answer (score 3):

The surest way to get those pages out of index is to use this in the HTML head section:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
```

Sometimes Google indexes some URLs (but not the content) despite the `Disallow` in *robots.txt*. See my [answer to this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/34546/google-indexing-page-with-parameters-but-page-is-disallowed-in-robots-txt/48337#48337) for details.